# hadoop delete file which is zero byte

Tags: hdfs, zero

I am looking for a command in hadoop 2.x to delete files which are Zero bytes in hdfs.
Can any one please let me know appropriate command.
I am trying to find the files that has are of zero bytes in hdfs and delete them from the directory.

Answer (score 14):

```
for f in $(hdfs dfs -ls -R / | awk '$1 !~ /^d/ && $5 == "0" { print $8 }'); do hdfs dfs -rm "$f"; done
```

Step by step:

`hdfs dfs -ls -R /` - list all files in HDFS recursively

`awk '$1 !~ /^d/ && $5 == "0" { print $8 }')` - print full path of those being not directories and with size 0

`for f in $(...); do hdfs dfs -rm "$f"; done` - iteratively remove

Answer (score 6):

Building on Kombajn's answer, if you have a lot of files to delete it will be quicker to use `xargs`. This will allow you to delete multiple files per `hdfs` command, which is rather expensive.

```
hdfs dfs -ls -R / | awk '$1 !~ /^d/ && $5 == "0" { print $8 }' | xargs -n100 hdfs dfs -rm
```

Comment: @ylabidi to expand on what Kombajn described, he's printing field 8 (filename) for lines from `ls` that don't begin with 'd' (directories) and where the 5th field (size) isn't 0